# SonarQube code smell due to it ignoring `this` in two of three options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Here's an example of the issue I'm facing.

I suspect the reason I get [this error](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3800) on this block of code is because according to `javascript:3AS3800`...

> *Functions returning `this` are ignored.*

Assuming this is the case, I'm having trouble coming up with a clean workaround.

```js
    if (typeof (row) === 'string') {
      return (
        <Grid key={i}>
          <Divider className={classes.divider} />
            <Typography>
              { row }
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
      )
    }

    if (row.constructor === Array) {
      return row.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid key={index}>
          { this.getItem(item, formProps) }
        </Grid>
      ))
    }

    return (
      <Grid key={i}>
        { this.getItem(row, formProps) }
      </Grid>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I think a useful perspective is that this is not an "error", but an "issue". When SonarQube reports an issue, it uses all the information that is available to it, along with sometimes debatable guidelines. It's not going to be reasonable to "fix" all the issues that SonarQube reports.  In this case, if TypeScript works the way I think it's behaving, I don't think you can "fix" this at all.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, makes sense if my initial observation was the case however it was just pointed out to me that one return block is returning a list of grids while the rest aren't. Case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that might stumble upon this, I misunderstood the error message.

Sonarqube wants each return to be a value of the same `type`. In my example, the middle block returns a list of `Grid` components while the rest return solo `Grid` components. The solution was to return the solo `Grid` components as lists like so:

```js
    if (typeof (row) === 'string') {
      return ([
        <Grid key={i}>
          <Divider className={classes.divider} />
            <Typography>
              { row }
            </Typography>
        </Grid>,
      ])
    }

    if (row.constructor === Array) {
      return row.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid key={index}>
          { this.getItem(item, formProps) }
        </Grid>
      ))
    }

    return ([
      <Grid key={i}>
        { this.getItem(row, formProps) }
      </Grid>,
    ])
  }
```